# groups.exit(...).watchTransition is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a multi-bar chart in which I've assigned a click event to the bars.  This works fine until a user changes the chart type from grouped to stacked, at which point I've discovered that I need to reassign the onClick handler.  This all seems to work correctly.

The problem is that after my click handler runs, whether or not the user has changed the chart type yet previously, attempting to change the chart type will result in a "groups.exit(...).watchTransition is not a function" JS error.

Chart definition:

```
        nv.addGraph(function() {
            // Defining the chart itself
            var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
                .x(function(d) { return d.label })
                .y(function(d) { return d.value })
                .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 275})
                .showValues(true)           //Show bar value next to each bar.
                .tooltips(true)             //Show tooltips on hover.
                .valueFormat(d3.format('$,.2f'))
                .groupSpacing(0.5)
                .showControls(true);        //Allow user to switch between "Grouped" and "Stacked" mode.

            chart.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format('$,.2f'));

            d3.select('#chart2 svg')
                .datum(barData)
                .call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        },
        function(){
            // Set the click handler.  This part works fine, but the onclick handler goes away after changing the chart type and thus needs redefined below.
            // PROBLEM POINT: once this code is run, the user can no longer change the chart type.  They just keep getting "groups.exit(...).watchTransition is not a function"
            d3.selectAll(".nv-bar").on('click',
            function(e){
                var canName     = e.label.split('(');
                var canName     = $.trim(canName[0]);
                var searchTerm  = canName + ' ' + e.key;

                var detUrl      = "/details.cfm?canName=" + encodeURIComponent(canName) + "&searchTerm=" + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
                $("#detailsDiv").html("Loading...");
                $("#detailsDiv").load(detUrl);

                location.href = "#details";
            });

            // If I try to redefine the bar click handler in the radio button's "click" event it overwrites the built in JS used to change the chart type, so instead
            // I handle it onMouseUp.
            d3.selectAll(".nv-series").on('mouseup',
            function(e){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    // Just running this directly on mouseUp doesn't work.  Apparently the chart needs time to load first.  So we do it 100ms later, which works fine.
                    d3.selectAll(".nv-bar").on('click',
                    function(e){
                        var canName     = e.label.split('(');
                        var canName     = $.trim(canName[0]);
                        var searchTerm  = canName + ' ' + e.key;

                        var detUrl      = "/details.cfm?canName=" + encodeURIComponent(canName) + "&searchTerm=" + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
                        $("#detailsDiv").html("Loading...");
                        $("#detailsDiv").load(detUrl);

                        location.href = "#details";
                    });
                }, 100);
            });

        });
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43135066/2571060

Answer (score 3):

watchTransition is defined by nvd3 on D3's selection prototype, if you have nv.d3.js loaded in the browser, you should be able to step with the debugger into the following code before, any chart is rendered:

```
d3.selection.prototype.watchTransition = function(renderWatch){
    var args = [this].concat([].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return renderWatch.transition.apply(renderWatch, args);
};
```

I had the same issue. The reason was that I was using webpack, which bundled D3 inside my application, so the D3 that was used to draw the chart was not the D3 that NVD3 visits to add the function to the prototype. So if you are using webpack or browserify make sure to exclude D3 and add it only as reference script.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was spot on. We had angular2-nvd3 and ng2-nvd3 installed and one was effectively overwriting the other.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by downgrading to d3 3.4.4, as advised by [this comment](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1582#issuecomment-209690887).